# imac with second Apple screen on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display, mac, nvidia-geforce

After 2 weeks testing and failing to find a solution I decided to ask help. I'll summarize my situation.

```
imac 27" (from 2014) + Thunderbolt display 27" + Linux
```

It was working perfectly when I was using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in the past, but after some update, the second monitor didn't work.

So, I decided to clean my computer and installed a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

During the installation with the live USB it was working but after restarting, it is off.

I really need the second screen, so I appreciate any help from experts.

**Some notes:**

1. the display is connected via thunderbolt cable ([like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Thunderbolt-Connector.jpg/250px-Thunderbolt-Connector.jpg)) and the speakers and USB are working. Only the screen is off.
2. I tried to use the drivers: `nvidia-driver-390`, `nvidia-driver-340` and `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`.
3. I still have the partition with MacOS Mavericks updated and everything works well there.

**Some extra info**

**`uname -a`**

```
Linux lali 4.18.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 27 07:28:31 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**`lspci`**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104M [GeForce GTX 775M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
04:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
06:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
08:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
09:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
09:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
09:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
09:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
09:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
0a:00.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor Device 400c (rev 02)
0b:03.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor Device 400c (rev 02)
0c:00.0 USB controller: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X442SL USB OHCI Controller (rev 01)
0c:00.1 USB controller: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X442SL USB OHCI Controller (rev 01)
0c:00.2 USB controller: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X442SL USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
0d:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
0e:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller (rev 08)
```

**`xrandr`**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1280x720      59.86  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**`lsmod`**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nvidia_uvm            757760  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
uvcvideo               94208  0
gpio_ich               16384  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
nvidia_drm             40960  2
videobuf2_common       40960  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
applesmc               20480  0
input_polldev          16384  1 applesmc
videodev              188416  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
nvidia_modeset       1048576  11 nvidia_drm
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
nvidia              14376960  485 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
btintel                20480  1 btusb
bluetooth             552960  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             208896  0
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo
kvm                   626688  1 kvm_intel
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 nvidia_drm
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_usb_audio         225280  5
snd_usbmidi_lib        32768  1 snd_usb_audio
drm                   458752  5 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_codec_cirrus    20480  1
input_leds             16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_cirrus
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  8
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
wl                   6447104  0
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
aesni_intel           200704  0
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_rawmidi            32768  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_pcm                98304  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
cfg80211              667648  1 wl
snd                    81920  38 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_cirrus,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
acpi_als               16384  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
industrialio           69632  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
soundcore              16384  1 snd
lpc_ich                24576  0
apple_bl               16384  0
video                  45056  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  4
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   122880  2 usbhid,hid_generic
firewire_ohci          40960  0
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
thunderbolt           122880  0
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
ahci                   40960  3
tg3                   167936  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
sdhci_pci              36864  0
cqhci                  24576  1 sdhci_pci
sdhci                  49152  1 sdhci_pci
```